# Elementos de B cujos índices são as posições das ocorrências de elementos iguais em A

Tags: python, python-2.7

Se eu tiver as listas:

```
A = [12,   15,  10,  15,  12,  10,  10,  10,  15,  12,  12,  15,  15,  15]
B = [0.2, 0.3, 1.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.7, 0.4, 0.6, 0.1, 0.3, 0.7, 0.4, 0.5, 0.5]
```

Como é que eu posso agrupar em listas separadas os valores de B que estão nas posições de elementos repetidos em A? Apresentado por exemplo:

```
nova_lista(12) = [0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.7]
nova_lista(15) = [0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.4, 0.5, 0.5]
```

Tentei este código mas além de dar erro também não me faz sentido...

```
nova_lista_12 = [x for x in A if A[x]==A[x+1]]
print nova_lista_12
```

Comment: Não tem nenhum valor de B que seja igual ao de A. Acredito que existe funções para fazer uma interserção, diferença, união de listas. Poderia explicar melhor e se possível fazer um exemplo no ideone?

Comment: O que eu pretendo é, encontrar os indices de A cujos elementos são iguais (sempre que são 12 ou sempre que são 15, ou 10) e numa lista nova colocar os valores de B desses indices repetidos.
Assim para o valor 12 de A, teria uma lista: nova_lista_12=[0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.7] com os valores de B dos indices em que A é 12...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro, vamos criar uma coleção a partir de A sem valores repetidos:

```
ASemRepetidos = set(A)
```

Para cada elemento desse conjunto, vamos encontrar os índices das ocorrências dele em A. Quando precisa de índices, a função `enumerate` é sua amiga. Com a ajuda dela e de uma *list comprehension*, montamos essa função:

```
def indicesDeElementoNaLista(elementoProcurado, lista):
    return [i for (i, elemento) in enumerate(lista) if elemento == elementoProcurado]
```

Com isso, precisamos obter os valores de B correspondentes a essas posições. Vamos fazer outra função para isso:

```
def elementosNasPosicoes(lista, posicoes):
    return [lista[i] for i in posicoes]
```

Com essas funções, vamos ao nosso programa:

A estrutura de dados mais adequada para gerar variáveis "dinamicamente", como você está querendo com suas `nova_lista(x)` é o *mapeamento*, ou, no linguajar de Python, um *dicionário*. Vamos criar um dicionário cujas chaves são os elementos únicos de A e valores são os valores correspondentes de B. Com as funções acima, fica simples:

```
dicionarioResultante = {} # coloque um nome mais adequado ao seu contexto

for elemento in ASemRepetidos:
    posicoes = indicesDeElementoNaLista(elemento, A)
    elementosCorrespondentes = elementosNasPosicoes(B, posicoes)
    dicionarioResultante[elemento] = elementosCorrespondentes

print(dicionarioResultante)
```

Aplicando isso ao seu exemplo de entrada, temos a saída:

```
{10: [1.1, 0.7, 0.4, 0.6], 12: [0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.7], 15: [0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.4, 0.5, 0.5]}
```

Um exemplo de uso do resultado:

```
for chave in ASemRepetidos:
    print("Número: " + str(chave) + ". Valores correspondentes de B: " + str(dicionarioResultante[chave]))
```

Ou, usando apenas os métodos do dicionário (mais interessante caso seu código esteja modularizado e B esteja fora de escopo):

```
for chave in dicionarioResultante.keys():
    print("Número: " + str(chave) + ". Valores correspondentes de B: " + str(dicionarioResultante[chave]))
```

Comment: Obrigada, de facto faz o que eu preciso!!
Mas eu não sei bem como funcionam os dicionários.. Como posso por exemplo somar os valores que pertencem ao 10 ? Se fizer dicionarioResultante.values() vou buscar as listas do 10, 12 e 15, certo? como vou buscar só a do 10 para depois somar os elementos?

Comment: dicionarioResultante[10]. Pra somar, use a função sum.

Comment: E não há uma forma mais geral do tipo dicionarioResultante[indice], pois caso a lista seja muito grande com muitos pares chave/valor se torne algo mais fácil de fazer?

Comment: Não entendi. Qual é o problema com essa forma?

Comment: Era para tornar o código aplicável a outros estudos, se os valores das listas mudarem todos e se as listas forem maiores. Em vez de ter que visualizar a lista A para saber quais as chaves, se havia uma forma de escrever em vez de dicionarioResultante[10], por exemplo com um ciclo que percorresse ASemRepetidos, uma vez que esta lista é a das chaves

Comment: Sim, claro. A ideia é você fazer um `for` em `ASemRepetidos` e fazer `dicionarioResultante[elementoDeASemRepetidos]` . Eu deixei essa parte de fora porque não há nada semelhante no seu código. É similar a uma lista. Vou colocar um exemplo.

Comment: @SofiaRaimundo Pronto. Dê uma olhada.

Comment: Era exatamente isso que eu estava a tentar pedir, obrigada!!

Comment: Como é que eu posso saber o índice dos repetidos a primeira vez que eles aparecem na lista original A e não o seu índice na lista de sem repetidos (ASemRepetidos)? Ou seja, eu queria uma função que me retornasse que o índice de 12 é 0, que o de 15 é 1 e que o de 10 é 2?

Comment: `suaLista.index(valorBuscado)`. Evite de fazer novas perguntas nos comentários. Use esse campo apenas para solicitar esclarecimentos ou complementar uma resposta. Se tiver uma dúvida nova, abra uma nova pergunta (e busque antes se ela já não está respondido).

Comment: mas eu queria que me devolvesse os indices das chaves todas, para não fazer um a um e ser mais geral, tentei este código mas não deu...
indice=[]
for k in range(0,len(A)):
    for chave in ASemRepetidos:
        indice.append(A.index(chave))
print indice

Comment: Umas das funções que eu escrevi na resposta não faz justamente isso?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38077/discussion-between-sofia-raimundo-and-pablo-almeida).

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> A = [12,   15,  10,  15,  12,  10,  10,  10,  15,  12,  12,  15,  15,  15]
>>> B = [0.2, 0.3, 1.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.7, 0.4, 0.6, 0.1, 0.3, 0.7, 0.4, 0.5, 0.5]
>>> 
>>> D = {}
>>>
>>> for (i,key) in enumerate(A):
...  D.update({key:[B[i]] if not D.has_key(key) else D[key]+[B[i]]})
... 
>>> print D
{10: [1.1, 0.7, 0.4, 0.6], 12: [0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.7], 15: [0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.4, 0.5, 0.5]}
>>> print D[12]
[0.2, 0.2, 0.3, 0.7]
>>> print D[15]
[0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.4, 0.5, 0.5]
```